# Find the value of k in $(k+2)x^2+4k=(4k+2)x$ if the equation has two equal roots.

Tags: functions

Can you help me answer the question above?

My problem has consistently been with trying to find the a, b and c values for these kinds of equations.

Any advice on how?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Where do you have a difficulty?

Comment: It has to do with discriminant.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the discriminant of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$. It is:

$$\Delta=b^2-4ac=(4k+2)^2-4\cdot 4k(k+2)=16k^2+16k+4-16k^2-32k=-16k+4$$

A quadratic two equal roots if and only if $\Delta=0$ i.e. $k=1/4$

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the equation, collecting up the terms in $x^2$, $x$ and the remaining constant terms. In this case, most of that has already been done for you. You just need to move everything to one side of the equation: $$\underbrace{(k+2)}_ax^2 \underbrace{- (4k+2)}_b x + \underbrace{4k}_c = 0.$$ Let’s say that the equation had instead been presented as $$k(4-4x+x^2)=2x(1-x).$$ Expand everything: $$4k-4kx+kx^2 = 2x-2x^2,$$ move everything to the same side of the equation: $$4k-4kx+kx^2 - 2x+2x^2 = 0,$$ rearrange to collect like terms: $$kx^2+2x^2-4kx-2x+4k = 0,$$ factor: $$(k+2)x^2-(4k+2)x+4k = 0.$$ It sounds like you know what to do with these coefficients once you’ve identified them.